# Javascript result is the function as a string not the array element I was expecting

Tags: javascript

my JavaScript object has an array in it but when I try to return an element of the array I get the function as a string instead of the value of the array element.

My code is

```
  function Car(make, model){
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.dimensions = [4, 3, 1.8];
    this.carLength = function(){ return this.dimensions[0]; };
  }

  var c = new Car("Ford", "Escort");

  alert(c.make);
  alert(c.model);
  alert(c.dimensions[0]);
  alert(c.carLength);
```

The first 3 alerts show the data expected, ("Ford", "Escort" and 4), the forth one displays the following output

```
function(){ return this.dimensions[0]; }
```

Why is the function being listed and not executed?

Comment: `CarInstance.carLength` is a method. You have to call it, or you'll just get the function. `console.log(c.carLength())`

Comment: Because this is a function, to execute use () at the end. Example: `alert(c.carLength())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include parentheses to execute the function.

```
alert(c.carLength());
```

If you don't include the parentheses, then you are just passing a reference to the function into the `alert` function as a variable. Then `alert` will execute `toString()` on that variable.

When you include the parentheses, you are passing the value that is returned from executing the function.